# javascript focus on pop up window

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript focus on pop up window.pop up window should always be focussed.
my javascript code

```
<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
    popupWindow=window.open('test.php','title:this.title', 'width=1000','height=800' , 'scrollbars=yes');
    popupWindow.focus();
    }

    </script>
```

what i want is pop up window should always be in front even if do any activity..
even if u open new tab pop up window should always be focussed.. i have tried many other codes but it dint work..can anyone please help me in sovling this problem.

Comment: _"even if [you] open [a] new tab"_ - That sounds like a rather obnoxious thing to (try to) do to your users.

Comment: Thankfully, this isn't possible. Even `showModalDialog()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

Another approach: You can have a javascript in test.php which will look of DOM ready and perform some focus function over there.

;)